# add text to a-frame window from a form

Tags: javascript, html, webvr

How to add text from a form in the a-frame window

```js
$("#text1").click(function(e){
     var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        //document.write(x);
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;
        return false;   
   });
```

```html
<form name="myForm" href="" onsubmit="text" >
  id: <input type="number" value="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<a-entity text="output" value="output"></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setAttribute`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-componentname-value-propertyvalue-clobber) to change the value of the text component on the entity.

There were also some other problems with your code that I've fixed below.

```js
$("#text1").click(function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("output").setAttribute("text", "value", x);
  return false;
});
```

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" href="" onsubmit="text">
  id: <input type="number" value="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
  <input id="text1" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<a-scene background="color: black">
  <a-entity id="output" text="value: output; align: center;" position="0 1.6 -0.5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access your a-entity element by ID, I suppose, this element must have ID setted 
`<a-entity id="output"></a-entity>`
[A-FRAME docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/entity.html#retrieving-an-entity)